# How to show the loop integral of $\frac{1}{z-a}$ vanishes...

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

...when the loop is a positively oriented circle $C$ and $a$ lies outside of $C$?

My work so far has been to show $\frac{1}{z-a}$ is contimuous when $z\neq a$. As such, every loop integral of $\frac{1}{z-a}$ (where the loop does not contain $a$) $=0$, i.e. vanishes. Since $C$ does not contain $a$, this applies to $\int_C\frac{1}{z-a}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The function $\frac1{z-a}$ has antiderivative $\log(z-a)$, which is analytic inside and on $C$ when $a$ is outside of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac1{z-a}$ is actually holomorphic on the simply connected region enclosed by $C$.  [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Statement_of_theorem)  tells us the integral is zero.  Notice this would be the *winding number*.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not correct. You just mentioned that $C$ does not contain $a$, but you did not actually use that hypothesis. So, the argument should also be valid when $C$ contains $a$, but then the integral is not $0$.

If $C$ doesn't contain $a$, you can find an open half-plane $H$ containing $C$ such that $a\notin H$. SInce $H$ is simply connected, the restraction of $\frac1{z-a}$ to $H$ has a primitive $F$. And so, since $C\colon[b,c]\longrightarrow H$ is a loop,$$\int_C\frac{\mathrm dz}{z-a}=F\bigl(C(c)\bigr)-F\bigl(C(b)\bigr)=0.$$